# Select N records statement not returning correct amount

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ms-access

I am using a sql statement to connect to an access db and retrieve only 100 records. However, this is returning ALL records and not 100. How do I limit the records I want to fetch. If I run this statement in access directly as a query, it works fine.

I am using winforms in vb.Net.Thanks

```
sql = "Select top 100 * from Requests ORDER BY [Date-time received] DESC"
```

**vb.Net code**

```
    Dim lvcount As Integer = 0
    'Dim tmpColor As Color = Color.Green

    Sub fillRequests()
        Try

            DBConnection.connect()

            sql = "Select top 100 * from Requests ORDER BY [Date-time received] DESC"

            Debug.Print(sql)

            Dim oledbCmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, oledbCnn)


            Using dr = oledbCmd.ExecuteReader()

                While dr.Read()
                    If dr.HasRows Then
                        Dim LVI As New ListViewItem

                        With LVI

                            .UseItemStyleForSubItems = False

                            .Text = dr(0).ToString()

                            .SubItems.Add(CDate(dr(5)).ToShortDateString)
                            .SubItems.Add(dr(1).ToString())
                            .SubItems.Add(dr(3).ToString())

                            If dr(3).ToString = "D" Then
                                .SubItems(3).Text = "Destruction"

                            ElseIf dr(3).ToString = "O" Then
                                .SubItems(3).Text = "Retrieval"

                            ElseIf dr(3).ToString = "I" Then
                                .SubItems(3).Text = "Intake"

                            ElseIf dr(3).ToString = "B" Then
                                .SubItems(3).Text = "Return"

                            ElseIf dr(3).ToString = "X" Then
                                .SubItems(3).Text = "Other"

                            ElseIf dr(3).ToString = "1" Then
                                .SubItems(3).Text = "Supply std boxes"

                            ElseIf dr(3).ToString = "G" Then
                                .SubItems(3).Text = "File Return"

                            ElseIf dr(3).ToString = "F" Then
                                .SubItems(3).Text = "File Retrieval"

                            ElseIf dr(3).ToString = "2" Then
                                .SubItems(3).Text = "Supply prt boxes"

                            End If


                            .SubItems.Add(dr(9).ToString())

                            If IsDBNull(dr(9)) Then
                                .SubItems(4).Text = "O/S"
                                .SubItems(4).ForeColor = Color.Red
                                'MessageBox.Show(.SubItems(4).Text)

                            ElseIf dr(9) IsNot "DEMO" Then
                                .SubItems(4).Text = "Done"

                            End If

                        End With
                        lvRequests.Items.Add(LVI)

                        lvcount += 1

                    End If

                End While
            End Using

            'autosize each column in listview

            For Each col As ColumnHeader In lvRequests.Columns
                col.Width = -2
            Next col

            'refresh the list with new data
            'lvRequests.Refresh()

            'Enable the posting previous button
            btnPreviousPostings.Enabled = False
            btnPreviousPostings.Text = "No data to show"
            oledbCnn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            'dr.Close()
            'oledbCnn.Close()
        End Try

        'btnNextPostings.Enabled = ListView1.Items.Count > 100

        If (lvRequests.Items.Count < 100) Then
            btnNextPostings.Enabled = False
            btnNextPostings.Text = "No data to show"
        Else
            btnNextPostings.Enabled = True
            btnNextPostings.Text = "Next " & CStr(lvRequests.Items.Count - 1) & " Postings"
        End If

        'RESET LVCOUNT TO 0
        lvcount = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Show us the VB code that you are using to define and execute the query.

Comment: Are you using the `count` variable to determine how many rows are returned?  If so, it looks like it's a module/class level variable and you're not setting it to zero before your loop.

Comment: I am using Dim lvcount As Integer = 0 as a counter. Thanks

Comment: I then reset lvcount = 0 outside the loop.

Comment: There is nowhere in this code that you reset your counter.

Comment: It is just before the closing sub.

Comment: It may be best if I post the whole code.

Comment: Whole code now posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [office.microsoft.access.help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/all-distinct-distinctrow-top-predicates-HP001032205.aspx)

> The TOP predicate does not choose between equal values.

So if all your records have same value in `[Date-time received]`, then query return all rows.

**Workaround**:
If you have for example `ID`-field(or some another field, but with unique values) in your table `Requests` then use it in `ORDER`

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Requests ORDER BY [Date-time received] DESC, [ID] DESC
```

Comment: Fabio, what I am trying to do is a sort of pagination. There are many records so I need to split them into postings of 100. How do I capture the next 100 records as per my code example. Thanks

Comment: Use `DataTable`. Fill it with your data(all rows) then you can do what you want having all rows(data) in one object

Comment: Do you have example or help amend my code to achieve this. I am fairly new to vb.net and still finding my way. Thanks

Comment: Check this [Retrieve DataTable](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/08/25/retrieve-a-datatable-using-microsoft-access.aspx) and [Looping through DataTable](http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/120623/Looping-through-a-returned-rows-in-DataTable-in-VBNet-and-ASPNet/). Try and if stack somewhere ask new question(because this question about another thing)

Answer (score 0):

Just a workaround: If it is not huge data you can get the result into some collection and then  get the top 100 items from that collection(I suppose it would be easy using vb.NET) and dispose others off.